# Generate variables by many different groups

Tags: stata, generate

I have a dataset with:

1. A unique `person_id`.
2. Different subjects that the person took in the past (`humanities`, `IT`, `business` etc.).
3. The `Degree` of each subject.

This looks as follows:

```
person_id humanities business IT   Degree
1           0       1         0     BSc
1           0       0         1     MSc
2           1       0         0     PhD
2           0       1         0     MSc
2           0       0         1     BSc
3           0       0         1     BSc
```

I would like to transform this dataset so that I have variables consisting of each possible combination of degree and subject for each `person_id`.

The idea is that when I `collapse` it later by `person_id`, I will have one value for each person (namely `0` or `1`). I have twelve different subjects and four main degrees.

```
person_id humanities business IT   Degree  BSc_humanities  MSc_Hum 
1           0          1       0    BSc              0         0
1           0          0       1    MSc              0         0
2           1          0       0    PhD              0         1
2           1          0       0    MSc              0         1
2           0          0       1    BSc              0         1
3           0          0       1    BSc              0         0
```

What would be the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fillin`:

```
clear

input person_id humanities business IT  str3 Degree
1           0       1         0     BSc
1           0       0         1     MSc
2           1       0         0     PhD
2           0       1         0     MSc
2           0       0         1     BSc
3           0       0         1     BSc
end

fillin person_id humanities business Degree

list person_id humanities business Degree

     +-----------------------------------------+
     | person~d   humani~s   business   Degree |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. |        1          0          0      BSc |
  2. |        1          0          0      MSc |
  3. |        1          0          0      PhD |
  4. |        1          0          1      BSc |
  5. |        1          0          1      MSc |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  6. |        1          0          1      PhD |
  7. |        1          1          0      BSc |
  8. |        1          1          0      MSc |
  9. |        1          1          0      PhD |
 10. |        1          1          1      BSc |
     |-----------------------------------------|
 11. |        1          1          1      MSc |
 12. |        1          1          1      PhD |
 13. |        2          0          0      BSc |
 14. |        2          0          0      MSc |
 15. |        2          0          0      PhD |
     |-----------------------------------------|
 16. |        2          0          1      BSc |
 17. |        2          0          1      MSc |
 18. |        2          0          1      PhD |
 19. |        2          1          0      BSc |
 20. |        2          1          0      MSc |
     |-----------------------------------------|
 21. |        2          1          0      PhD |
 22. |        2          1          1      BSc |
 23. |        2          1          1      MSc |
 24. |        2          1          1      PhD |
 25. |        3          0          0      BSc |
     |-----------------------------------------|
 26. |        3          0          0      MSc |
 27. |        3          0          0      PhD |
 28. |        3          0          1      BSc |
 29. |        3          0          1      MSc |
 30. |        3          0          1      PhD |
     |-----------------------------------------|
 31. |        3          1          0      BSc |
 32. |        3          1          0      MSc |
 33. |        3          1          0      PhD |
 34. |        3          1          1      BSc |
 35. |        3          1          1      MSc |
     |-----------------------------------------|
 36. |        3          1          1      PhD |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```